# Delete group-box with labels inside using index

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am trying to delete a group-box with a label. The group-box is created using a func that is runed when a button is pressed. The group-box is a scroll area with vertical layout while the lable has grid layout. I have searched the web but there were no convenient method using index. I thought to access group-box using index and delete. Here's the code:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.sip import delete


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(363, 260)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 300, 121))
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 84))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 281, 172))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 363, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "add"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "delete"))

    def add(self):
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 74))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText('label created')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
    def delete(self):
        self.verticalLayout.itemAt(0).deleteLater()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The following error is generated when I run delete function.

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'deleteLater'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to solve this but I could not fix this.The solutio is to replace this

```
self.verticalLayout.itemAt(0).deleteLater()
```

with

```
self.verticalLayout.itemAt(0).widget().deleteLater()
```

**Note:** widget fucntion was missinng in my code